# My array doesnt go past first vaule

Tags: python-2.7

For some reason the code indent isn't working for me on here. The "def cleanup():" is not indented and the rest is indented 1 past it. 
My problem is the array will print all 25 (estimante) of the values in the area when i use "print s" but as the code runs editing the outfile, it only prints the first value in the array. I cant figure out whats happening because "print s" produces what i want just fine.

```
   def cleanup():

infile = open('HDDprices-pre.txt')
outfile = open('HDDprices.txt', 'wt')
for s in hdd:
    line = infile.readline()
    #line = line.replace("('","")
    line = line.replace("Decimal('",s+": ")
    line = line.replace("'),","\n")
    line = line.replace("'))","")
    outfile.write(line)
    print s
infile.close()
outfile.close()
os.remove('HDDprices-pre.txt') #erase pre file
```

Content of hdd (located at top of script)

```
 hdd = ('HDD_Desktop_SATA_4TB, HDD_Desktop_SATA_3TB, HDD_Desktop_SATA_2TB, HDD_Desktop_SATA_1TB, HDD_Desktop_SATA_750GB, HDD_Desktop_SATA_500GB, HDD_Desktop_SATA_250GB, HDD_Desktop_SATA_200GB, HDD_Laptop_SATA_2TB, HDD_Laptop_SATA_1TB, HDD_Laptop_SATA_750GB, HDD_Laptop_SATA_500GB, HDD_Laptop_SATA_400GB, HDD_Laptop_SATA_320GB, HDD_Laptop_SATA_300GB, HDD_Laptop_SATA_250GB, HDD_Laptop_SATA_200GB, HDD_Laptop_SATA_160GB, HDD_Laptop_SATA_150GB, HDD_Laptop_SATA_120GB, HDD_Laptop_SATA_100GB, HDD_Desktop_IDE_750GB, HDD_Desktop_IDE_500GB, HDD_Desktop_IDE_400GB, HDD_Desktop_IDE_320GB, HDD_Desktop_IDE_250GB, HDD_SSD_512GB, HDD_SSD_480GB, HDD_SSD_256GB, HDD_SSD_250GB, HDD_SSD_240GB, HDD_SSD_160GB, HDD_SSD_128GB, HDD_SSD_80GB, HDD_SSD_64GB, HDD_SSD_60GB, HDD_SSD_32GB, HDD_SSD_30GB')
 hdd = hdd.split(',')
```

HDDprices-pre.txt

```
(Decimal('164.98'), Decimal('110.00'), Decimal('87.00'), Decimal('54.99'), Decimal('64.99'), Decimal('44.95'), Decimal('26.98'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('153.98'), Decimal('72.48'), Decimal('56.99'), Decimal('42.99'), Decimal('82.00'), Decimal('35.99'), Decimal('92.00'), Decimal('31.99'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('29.88'), Decimal('139.00'), Decimal('85.00'), Decimal('79.00'), Decimal('207.00'), Decimal('119.95'), Decimal('110.00'), Decimal('34.95'), Decimal('24.88'), Decimal('285.20'), Decimal('229.50'), Decimal('148.99'), Decimal('119.99'), Decimal('119.99'), Decimal('166.00'), Decimal('72.00'), Decimal('90.30'), Decimal('56.99'), Decimal('53.48'), Decimal('34.99'), Decimal('67.99'))
```

Comment: Your indendation seems to be messed up. Also, what's the content of the hdd variable, where do you assign it?

Comment: Is your HDDprices-pre.txt file empty or has it just one line? Or can you show us the first lines of that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have one line in your input file. Every "Decimal('" will be replaced by 'HDD_Desktop_SATA_4TB'. In the next iteration `readline()` will return an empty string.

Comment: How do i break that one line into serveral? Also, why does "print s" function correctly?

Comment: Got it, i just reran the replace since the previous broke it to new lines :)